# JSON deserialize issue in .NET

Tags: .net, json

I have a web API which is providing some JSON. I've checked the results in Postman to verify that they look correct. Here's the string it's returning:

```
[{"TranId":"1","Cost":"15.50","Distance":"0.0559887","StatusCode":"Arrived","TimeAccepted":"2019-05-11T17:49:08.197"}]
```

Then I have a Xamarin app where I'm trying to read the results from the API. Here's my code to make the API Call:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://...");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("1");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return result;
  }
```

For some reason the results look like this in the Locals window:

```
"\"[{\\\"TranId\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"Cost\\\":\\\"15.50\\\",\\\"Distance\\\":\\\"0.0559887\\\",\\\"StatusCode\\\":\\\"Arrived\\\",\\\"TimeA…"
```

I try to deserialize it using this line:

```
List<RootObject> customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore});
```

I used a tool to create the `RootObject` and all the columns are set to strings.

```
public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("TranId")]
        public string TranId { get; set; }
      ...
```

The error I keep getting looks like this:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "[{"TranId":"1", ...  }]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Fleet.Views.OrderDetails+RootObject]'. Path '', line 1, position 372.
```

If I manually replace the `json` variable with the string, the deserialization works. But in the Locals window the quotes only have a single backslash in front of them. I don't understand why they have 3 backslashes otherwise. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:
Here's the code from the endpoint:

```
ArrayList objs = new ArrayList();
while (reader.Read())
{
    objs.Add(new
    {
        TranId = reader["TranId"],
        Cost = reader["Cost"],
        Distance = reader["Distance"],
        StatusCode = reader["StatusCode"],
        TimeAccepted = reader["TimeAccepted"]

    });
}

returnValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objs);
```

Also if I try deserializing to a string a list of strings I get this error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Comment: There's two issues here. First, that weird syntax in that string is due to the debugger being "helpful" by styling it as a C# string literal value, which means escaping double quotes and so on. However, when we look past this, we have just a plain string, serialized to json. It's a bit hard to wrap your head around but you have serialized a string, as json. However, this string also *contains* json. You will need to do double deserialization here, first to a string, and then deserialize this to your objects.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of the endpoint you called as well?

Comment: Try just: `returnValue = objs;`

Comment: in addition to @LasseVågsætherKarlsen comment - you can view original value of escapped string by clicking on magnifier button next to that string in Locals and Debug window. It will open dialog with value as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The endpoint was returning `ActionResult<string>` so I changed that to a string and re-published. (I'm not sure if that made a difference.)

The response still did have extra backslashes in it as well as quotes around the whole thing. I had to check the first few characters individually to find this since even the magnifier option wasn't displaying the extra quotes. By removing these, it finally works!

```
json = json.Replace("\\", "");
json = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2);
```